# What happens if a non-Supe uses this substance?

Tags: the-boys, the-boys-2019

In *The Boys*, we learn of Vaught's

> Compound V

which:

> 1. appears to have been given to babies to create the Supes 
>  2. can be used by Supes to enhance their abilities 
>  3. has side effects similar to heroin 
>  4. has similarly addictive properties

**What happens if a non-superhero uses this substance?**

> Obviously here, I mean an individual who wasn't already enhanced as an infant.  Do they develop powers?  Do they still experience narcotic effects?   Addiction?   Death?

I will accept answers as relate to either/both the comics and the Amazon Prime series.

Comment: This is what was done to Kimiko (The Female). She was kidnapped as a child and turned into a child soldier in Homelander's supe-terrorist group. She was injected with the stuff as an adolescent/young adult (not sure on exact details hence why comment not answer), not as a baby.

Comment: They go over this in later episodes. IIRC, most die but some survive and gain powers.

Comment: @svenvo7:   Care to submit an answer?

Answer (score 5):

*Answering from the context of the Amazon series*

---

As far as Season 1 of *The Boys* is concerned, only two people have been shown to injected forcefully or willingly injected with Compound V.

1. **The Female**: A former member of the Shining Light Liberation Army. She managed to escape, however, and was taken prisoner and experimented on with Compound V. The Compound V gave her extraordinary abilities, but left her unable to talk making her the first on-screen character in *The Boys* who was given powers using Compound V as an adult. Her powers are listed [here](https://the-boys.fandom.com/wiki/The_Female).
2. **Naqib, the Super-terrorist**: In *Season-1 Episode-7 (The self-preservation society)*, it is revealed that Compound V has made its way to the middle-East and some terrorists got their hands on it creating a Super-Terrorist. Naqib, as he is called, was also injected with the serum while he was an adult. It is also later revealed that

   > it was Homelander who was responsible for smuggling out Compound V to the middle-East and creating this super terrorist.

### So, in short, Compound V has a similar effect of providing superpowers when injected in adults, as was the case for infants.

---

**Added note**: Compound V has been shown to create a sense of addiction in supes as seen in case of A-Train as he loses concentration and control if he doesn’t consume it on a regular basis.

It is also seen that his girlfriend (Popclaw) is addicted to Compound V.

Comment: It is mentioned (I believe by Stan Edgar) in the show that the results of administering compound V to a normal adult specimen are unpredictable and potentially fatal.

Answer (score 3):

Homelander tells Madelyn Stillwell that he flew around the Middle East and forcefully injected many people with Compound V. He says that

> Enough Survived to call this little experiment a success

Implying that the injection into a normal adult is probably pretty painful and violent, and that only a few survive the transformation to actually gain super powers.

Answer (score 1):

From the comics:

> Hughie, after he joins The Boys, intentionally receives a 'full-strength' dose of Compound V in order to permanently make him much more durable, so that he wouldn't immediately get torn apart by a low-level Supe in combat.  Images from issue #4:

---

> [image: Butcher injecting Hughie]

---

> [image: Hughie and Butcher discuss Compound V]

Answer (score 1):

Compound V is unstable. It could result in either powers or death if injected into a non-supe adult. According to Lamplighter in [Season 2 Episode 6 "The Bloody Doors Off"](https://the-boys.fandom.com/wiki/The_Bloody_Doors_Off):

> **Lamplighter** (*to M.M., Frenchie and Kimiko*)**:** Infants handle it best, but adults? I mean, you saw what happens--
> sometimes you get powers, sometimes you get a freak, sometimes you just explode.
> Vought is trying to stabilize it, so that you put the V in any adult arm, anywhere, anytime, you get a solid Supe, solid powers.

In [Season 3 Episode 1](https://the-boys.fandom.com/wiki/Payback_(episode)), it was revealed that Vought has developed [Temp V (V24)](https://the-boys.fandom.com/wiki/Compound_V#Variations), a modified version of Compound V that will give the user temporary supe powers, lasting around 24 hours. Butcher and Hughie use it and they become supes temporarily. In [Episode 7](https://the-boys.fandom.com/wiki/Here_Comes_a_Candle_to_Light_You_to_Bed), it was revealed that Temp V is lethal after 3-5 doses.